# Unique carbons on rings

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure

[image]

In rings in general, how do I determine how many unique carbons there are? In this example, I am thinking that there are 2 unique carbons (one on top and one with a double bond) since this molecule is symmetrical. Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, one would try to find points or lines of symmetry in general to check for equivalent ring atoms. It immensely helps to have a model and a lot of practice.

In your specific example, notice that you have two lines of symmetry in your (idealized) diagram: one passing through the sp3 carbons, and one crossing the two double bonds. You can thus "fold" the diagram into "quarters", leaving you with two non-equivalent atoms.

Comment: Don't think "fold" is the right word. The symmetry would be better expressed as rotations, reflections and inversion.

Comment: indeed that's the formal, mathematical way to put it, as reflections and other symmetry operations. I have a geometric mindset, so I always visualize things being literally sliced by planes, or being folded into equivalent halves or quarters

Comment: so based on this, how many unique carbons would benzene have? would it be 1?

Comment: yes $\phantom{}$